# Paths for children of routed Akka actors

Tags: akka

I have a routed Akka actor whose routees spawn child actors of another type. I have no need for the spawned children to be associated with a specific routee and am actually finding this to be a disadvantage. I'd expect to be able to address these children by the path `/RoutedActor/ChildActorName` but I'm finding them under a path that includes the routee's name: `/RoutedActor/$a/ChildActorName`. I have no idea which routee spawned a given child, so I've worked around this by wildcarding the path for my ActorSelections (`/RoutedActor/*/ChildActorName`).
This has got to be a pretty inefficient way to find an actor.

I understand that these children are actually *grandchildren* of the router, but this is really a big drawback in the router pattern. Just by adding routing to parallelize some work, I broke my ActorSelections and now don't know the actual path to any of my child actors. Is there a way to make the child actors direct children of the router, and if so, are there any disadvantages to this? I'm not finding anything on this in the Akka documentation (v2.3.7).

Comment: maybe consider simply passing the actorref around rather than using actor selection?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @YikSanChan. I considered this, but I'll need to keep some kind of registry of the ActorRefs up to date (the child actors are created and killed frequently). I'm losing a lot of the convenience of the actor system hierarchy if I have to manually track these actors.

Comment: I see, sounds a solid point. maybe refer to this post https://manuel.bernhardt.io/2018/03/20/akka-anti-patterns-overusing-actorselection/, it points out a solution that worths a try

Comment: Appreciate the response and the link. I'm familiar with the selection vs. ref performance differences. I'd rather the message end up in dead letters than pay the cost of resolving a ref or processing the response from an Identify message. I also still need the path to create the selection, so I think I'd still have this "which routee do you belong to?" issue.